# Importing momentjs by reference not working (typescript, amd)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, momentjs, amd

I am trying to understand out why this:

```
import * as moment from "../Typings/moment";
```

**works**, but this:

```
/// <reference path="../Typings/moment.d.ts" />
import * as moment from "moment";
```

**does not.** And throws the error: `cannot fine module 'moment'`.

The latter one works for libraries like react so I was expecting it to work for momentjs as well.

I am using the typings file from their git repo: https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation of momentjs says like this on import:

> If you have trouble importing moment, try add "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true in compilerOptions in your tsconfig.json file.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not fix the second case and still throws: `cannot find module 'moment'`